# How to get a url param in a django template?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I need to get the param of the url inside a html file, but I need to know if is possible in a tag, or how can I get the url params using Class-based views?

My urls.py file

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import UsersView


urlpatterns = [
    path('list/<int:pk>/', UsersView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
]
```

My html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Users</title>
</head>


<body>
    {{ request.GET.pk }}
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
self.kwargs['pk']
```

Inside a CBV to get the URL parameter, since there is a `<int:pk>`

Comment: I am a begginer, could you do a little example with code using it?

Comment: Since you mentioned that you can do a class-based view, this is one solution I can think of. You can do like `param = self.kwargs['pk']` inside a view function and do whatever with it. I don't think you can do it in a template tag since Django will treat it as a plain HTML file.

Comment: You can also try adding Javascript into the HTML template to grab the URL -- there are plenty of such methods online -- but I feel like doing everything in Django is cleaner.